# Note board as comment section

Tags: 2013, web-part, social

I have a note board in a page layout acting like a comment section.
I've created a page based on this page layout to display a image slider. The slider is loaded based on an ID that's passed through a query string.

In my development enviroment the note board show specific notes (comments) for each 'url' that I have.

Example:

**Url**: 'http//sps.com/SitePages/slider.aspx?id=**123**' |
**Comments**: 'foo', 'bar'

**Url**: 'http//sps.com/SitePages/slider.aspx?id=**321**' |
**Comments**: 'baz'

Changing the query string changed the notes loaded. Thas fine.

Now, in the production enviroment this two "different" URLs show the same comments, like all comments.

I haven't made any other customization so far. Only activated the feature for the note board webpart in both enviromments.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work as expected, just create your page in the Pages library. That was the difference between my dev and prod enviroments.